# PHPMailer : creating default object and undefined function clean_string()

Tags: php, html, forms, xampp, phpmailer

I'm kind of stuck with my code and I got two Errors.

The first one is...

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value on line 99
```

The second is...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function clean_string() on line 138.
```

It seems like I have some mistakes in my code:

```
 <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['result']) && $_GET['result'] == 'success') {
         echo '<div class="success_msg" > Tha`enter code here`nk you for contacting us. We will get back to you soon. </div> ';
    } ?>
    <style>
         .success_msg {
              background-color: #fed;
              color: green;
              border: 1px solid green; 
         }
    </style>
    <form name="contact-form" method="post" action="<?php echo  htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <table width="450px">
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top"">
    <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
    </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <input type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <input type="text" name="subject" maxlength="30" size="30">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <textarea name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
    </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

    <?php
    require_once("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php"); // this will include smtp and pop files.

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

       $email_to = "chrisperth03@gmail.com";

       function died($error) {// your error code can go here
            echo "We're sorry, but there's errors found with the form you submitted.<br /><br />";
            echo $error."<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
            die();
       }

       // validation expected data exists
       if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||!isset($_POST['last_name']) ||!isset($_POST['email']) ||!isset($_POST['telephone']) ||!isset($_POST['subject']) || !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
           died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.'); 
       }

       if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tsl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
        $mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
        $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

        // Authentication  
        $mail->Username   = "chrisperth03@gmail.com"; // Your full Gmail address
        $mail->Password   = "mypassword"; // Your Gmail password

       $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
       $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
       $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
       $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
       $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required
       $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

       $error_message = "";
       $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
       if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
           $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
       }
       $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
       if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
          $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
       }
       if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
           $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
       }
       if(!preg_match($string_exp,$subject)) {
          $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
       }
       if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
           $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
       }
       if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
           died($error_message);
       }
       $email_message = 
       $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
       $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
       $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
       $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
       $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
       $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";



      $mail = new PHPMailer();

       $mail->isSendmail();
       $mail->setFrom($email_from, $first_name.$last_name);
       $mail->addAddress($email_to, 'chrislopez');
       $mail->Subject = $subject;
       $mail->msgHTML($email_message);

       //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('path/to/file/attachment-file.extension'), dirname(__FILE__));

       if (!$mail->send()) { //send the message, check for errors
          echo "Mailer Error: " . died($error);
       } else {
           header('Location: contact.php?result=success'); 
       }
    ?>

    <!-- place your own success html below -->

    <?php
    }
    die();
    ?>
```

Comment: Where did you get this code? Wherever you copied it from, you didn;t get all of it.

Comment: I Got it on :  [link] http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/01/how-to-create-contact-form-with-phpmailer-to-send-mails/.  I just changed a few things.

Comment: Looks like a bad tutorial as they did not provide the complete source code. There's no way to know what that code exactly.

Comment: Ok i see.  thanks for you help  John Conde

Comment: The code that is there is quite broken too. I suggest you look at the simple contact form example provided with PHPMailer.